# Package for ItemListener class

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, itemlistener

I am learning java swing from the Dive Log tutorial. An object has been declared as the following:

```
ItemListener handler = new CheckBoxHandler();
```

The above produces a compilation error saying ItemListener class is missing.
The imports that have been made are as follow:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
```

Please tell me which import can solve the issue.
p.s. I think this bit of information is perhaps irrelevant, but still, I am using NetBeans IDE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For future reference, NetBeans can do the imports for you using `Ctrl+Shift+I`. If there are any conflicts, it will bring up a dialog asking which one you want. Still though, you should make a point of knowing how to find this out manually. The docs are a great place to look for those answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package is `java.awt.event`.

```
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
```

Comment: thanks, that solves the issue for Itemlistener. But now there is the same issue with checkboxhandler. One question that comes to my mind is I have already imported "java.awt.*" when the compilation error for ItemClassListener was showing up. So, does it not include the "java.awt.event.*" package?

Comment: CheckBoxHandler is probably your class or from a third-party package. The answer on the last question is: NO

Answer (score 1):

Oracle was so kind to [publish a documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) for this purpose ;)

The `ItemListener` is defined in `java.awt.event.ItemListener`.
You need therefore to `import java.awt.event.*;` since java doesn't import sub-namespaces automatically.

Answer (score 1):

**Interface** `ItemListener` is in the below package...

The package is `java.awt.event`